# querying on CheckSum generated values are resulting in returning null values

Tags: sql, azure-synapse, checksum, sql-view

I have a view in synapse database where we are trying to generate the Checksum based on couple fields as below. We used timestamp field to make this field to make this unique.

[Image of Checksum field combination in the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6J0g.png)

And when I tried to query for a single event where there are 3 images(records) for that event this is how results are like with id field which is the checksum generated value.

[Image of list of records per event id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IMPC.png)

Now If am trying to query this list with one of the generated value fields which is id I get some fields as blanks as per below.

[Image of querying view with single id (checksum)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBsaQ.png)

Here are how those null fields are coming from within the view

[Image of other fields which are coming back as nulls and how they are queried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX8gN.png)

I am able to understand what could be reason. Please help

I tried to alter the column combination to see if this would help but its been consistent.

```
 ABS(CHECKSUM(CONCAT_WS('||', [timestamp], event_id))) AS id, 
  .(other fields here)
  .
  .
  'jpg' AS before_format,
   'jpg' AS after_format,
   event_id
```

This is the query to select on the id (generated with checksum) on the same view where the results are blank for last 3 fields.

```
SELECT * FROM [HSTG]. 
[vw_HSTG_UDLXXXXX_XXXX_XXXX_VXXXXXXXX_XXX_XXXXX]
 WHERE id=1327508796
```

Comment: Please share your code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Added the code from the view

Comment: check if you can convert the timestamp to a string format